# Does the latest DirectX SDK support both Direct3D 9.0c and 11?

Tags: directx, directx11, directx9

1) What is the latest version of DirectX SDK?

2) For my purposes I need DirectX 9.0c SDK and DirectX 11 SDK. Do I need to install these libraries separately or last DirectX SDK package contains both of versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest SDK version, as of this writing, is the [June 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6812). It contains what you'd need to build against both 9.0c and 11.

Comment: In fact with the latest microsoft ide's, the old 9c sdk wont even work with the compiler, so get the newest.

Comment: Note that the DX SDK has been rolled into the Windows SDK.